# Keeping transaction date when updating e-commerce data via Measurement protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am updating transactions via Measurement Protocol when revenue changes. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to keep the date of the original transaction and just update their revenue.

How it is:

```
12/12/2017 ID#12345 $50
Update on 12/01/2018: revenue -$20
12/01/2018 ID#12345 $-20
```

= two transactions (and dates) with the correct combined revenue

How it *should* be

```
12/12/2017 ID#12345 $50    
Update on 12/01/2018: -$20  
12/12/2017 ID#12345 $30
```

= one transaction with the correct revenue

Comparisons to other months or years wouldn't otherwise be wrong, because the initial date of the transaction is more important than the date of the update.
Is there a way to update the original transaction data rather than pushing a new one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add an example of what you have tried or resources you have used, based on what you have tried explain what is not working as you expect. We are not here to give you full solutions. Read SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's more of a basic question wether updating existing transactions rather than pushing new ones is possible in general. I worked through the official documentation and searched for information on this, but didn't find anything. Thanks again!